# PID exit status from a while ago?

Tags: linux

lets say I was saving multiple PID #s, if i wanted to check the exit status of something that lets say ended 20 minutes ago, what can I do?

I've tried googling and havent gotten anything except for 'echo $?' ...

What I would like to be able to do is do 'echo $?' for a certain PID #

Answer (score 0):

When a process ends, its parent can read the termination status. Shell executes processes, it reads their termination status into the `?` variable. Once you execute another process and it terminates, the original value of `?` is overwritten.

The only chance for you is saving the exit status and the PID, but this is not easy in shell.

Comment: But if you want to do something like this, there may be a way to solve your problem without it. What problem are you exactly trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the log file for more information. ex: /var/log/messages,/var/log/syslog or any specific log file .

If your program is not writing the pid to a log file, you can write a script and append the pid status to your log file

```
echo $$ >>pid.history.log
```